# Is there a way to update Web form UI when one thread completes a task and the other is running

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, user-interface, webforms

I am working on Web Forms and using threading. How do I update my UI after completion of one thread process while another thread is performing some long running task? Basically I am creating a UI which will show audit logs periodically which are running by long running task/thread.

Comment: look for websockets or signalr if you are talking about web application.

Comment: Don't thread web pages like this, use AJAX

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I use SignalR for this. You can find it as a NuGet package. Here is a link to an introduction to it: [Introduction to SignalR | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr)

To achieve what you are looking for, you'd have to set up SignalR, then make a call to your Hub whenever you want to make an update to the Client Screen / UI. There are a lot of guides online, especially for chat apps. Here is one I used for writing a progress bar that you might find useful: [SignalR Progress Bar | CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1124691/%2FArticles%2F1124691%2FSignalR-Progress-Bar-Simple-Example-Sending-Live-D)